# Azure website and custom fonts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, devexpress, azure-web-app-service

So I am using a azure website not a web role. Just to be clear.

I am using the DevExpress components to export a report, `XRReport`.

I am trying to use a custom font within these reports. Under normal circumstances the `XRReport` component would load fonts from the Operating System.

I have tried using `PrivateFontCollection` to assign the fonts from the code behind.

```
private void XtraReport1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    PrivateFontCollection fontColl = new PrivateFontCollection();
    fontColl.AddFontFile("YourFont.ttf");

    XtraReport1 report = (XtraReport1)sender;
    foreach (Band b in report.Bands)
    {
        foreach (XRControl c in b.Controls)
        {                    
            c.Font = new Font(fontColl.Families[0], c.Font.Size, c.Font.Style);
        }
    }
}
```

However assigning the fonts in this way generates red crosses. See image below.
[image: Error]

The solution in my mind is one of two things.

1. I have seen some scripts to install fonts in web-roles, is there some way to do this in a website?
2. Is there a different way to assign the fonts in the code behind that works?

### UPDATE

Using the code from [UsherNet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070487/ushernet).

```
DevExpress.XtraPrinting.Export.Pdf.PdfGraphics.EnableAzureCompatibility = true;
```

The PDF does render now, but they custom font does not appear to have been loaded.

Comment: Do you get 404 errors when browser tries to get font-files? Or is your reporting component generates images with styled text on server-side?

Comment: The font file exists as it is also used in a stylesheet and works locally. Yes the report components are all generated server-side.

Comment: Reason I asked about 404s, sometimes azure-website needs restarting after deploying, so it adds extra handlers for new file extensions (that does not look like your issue). But if it all server-side, I'm out of suggestions. Quick search shows that Azure can add fonts, but you already tried it. Can you ask DevExpress support about it?

Answer (score 1):

the issue is caused by trust settings on Azure. The quickest solution is to set the property:

```
DevExpress.XtraPrinting.Export.Pdf.PdfGraphics.EnableAzureCompatibility = true;
```

More information can be found on the Support Centre web site. http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q373195

I have published a few report based projects on Azure recently and found the above takes care of the problem described.

Comment: That renders the report but the custom font is not being used?